# passport difference between LocalStrategy and ClientPasswordStrategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm a little bit confused with this strategies and do not clearly understand difference between them, and which of them I need to use in my application? (Or even need it in general), because I only need to exchange user credential to token, and then plann to use `bearer strategy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**LocalStrategy** is used to authenticate with [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) which means the user's username and password is sent base64 encoded in the Authentication header.

**ClientPasswordStrategy** is something very different and unless you are building your own OAuth provider you won't need it. It authenticates the `id` and `secret` of a client in the request body. Please note that the id and secret in this case are the application's credentials, not the user credentials.